# Oracle NUMBER to double bug?

Tags: oracle11g, odbc

In the following code, I'm using Oracle 11g expression edition. When getting column data, if the source is NUMBER(16,3) but the bound data is SQL_C_DOUBLE, there seems to be some error in the conversion.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace OracleNumberConversionTestCSharp
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection();

         connection.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1}; Dbq=127.0.0.1/XE; Uid=System; Pwd=password;";

         connection.Open();

         //Drop the table from a previous run
         OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("DROP TABLE ORACLE_NUMBER_TEST",connection);

         try
         {
            //would fail if table hasn't been created yet
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch
         {

         }

         //Create the table
         command = new OdbcCommand("CREATE TABLE ORACLE_NUMBER_TEST (MYNUM NUMBER(16,3))",connection);

         command.ExecuteNonQuery();

         //Insert the value
         command = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO ORACLE_NUMBER_TEST (MYNUM) values (2014056132407.123)",connection);

         command.ExecuteNonQuery();

         //Get the value back from the db
         command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT MYNUM FROM ORACLE_NUMBER_TEST",connection);

         OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

         if (reader.HasRows)
         {
            double expected = 2014056132407.123;
            double actual = reader.GetDouble(0);

            Console.WriteLine("Actual   = " + actual.ToString("R"));
            Console.WriteLine("Expected = " + expected.ToString("R"));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The results are:

```
Actual   = 2014056132407.12
Expected = 2014056132407.123
```

This is fixed using a couple of methods:

1. Change SELECT statement to: `SELECT CAST (MYNUM AS BINARY_DOUBLE) FROM ORACLE_NUMBER_TEST`
2. Change code from: `double actual = reader.GetDouble(0);` to `double actual = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetDecimal(0));`

I get the same behavior if I code the example in C. The analogous SQL in SQL Server and MySQL returns the expected result. Does this seem like a bug in the conversion from Oracle NUMBER to double in the Oracle driver, or is this within the parameters of acceptable behavior?

Comment: The `OraClient12Home1` reference suggests you're using the 12c driver to connect to connect to your 11g DB; which should be fine, but do you see the same behaviour with other driver versions?

Comment: Yes, the v11 driver has the same result